# Account Recovery Page is not Working

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts, account-recovery

I have registered using akshar26@gmail.com(user:6081031) on StackOverflow. I reset my password using account recovery page. Now, after resetting, It has created a new account and I have completely lost access to 6081031. In new account, I try to add email akshar26@gmail.com, it says:

"Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account."

Whenever I try to reset a password using account recovery page, it only creates a new account but my email is still associated with 6081031. This is weird. What can I do now?

Comment: Can you link to the newly created account so I can take a look?

Comment: New: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6129922/akshar-patel

Comment: Old: http://stackoverflow.com/users/6081031/iakshar

Comment: Any chance you created your first account using Stack Exchange OpenID? This would explain things here. /cc @Oded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've manually merged the accounts - there was only one OpenId provider registered on the old account (you may have deleted the others), but it was still registered with the same email address.

Comment: Awesome :-) Everything is perfect now. The Fastest Support Experience I have ever had in my Life. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AksharPatel consider yourself lucky that Oded is on "bug watch" today. :-) Anyway, was he right assuming you removed logins via your "Edit profile" page?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I am lucky. I didn't remove but reset my password and the problem happened from there on. Before posting here I actually searched on google and I found all the negative comments about stackoverflow being rude, strict and community of trolls. But, now I can say that they were all wrong. Oded has really changed my perception. Such a quick support. It is totally awesome. :)